# Using SDL_LoadBMP on 2 of the same image, but SDL_GetRGB is giving differing rgb values

Tags: c, image-processing, sdl, pixel

So I'm trying to write some code for compare 2 images at a pixel level with SDL and I'm running into some issues:

```
SDL_Surface* image1 = NULL;
SDL_Surface* image2 = NULL;
image1 = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/uclinux/Pictures/dogs.bmp");
image2 = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/uclinux/Pictures/dogs.bmp");
uint8_t r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2 = 0xFF;

for (i = 0; i < 640; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 480; j++)
    {   
        get_pixel_rgb(image1, i, j, &r1, &g1, &b1);
        get_pixel_rgb(image2, i, j, &r2, &g2, &b2);

            //print pixel values
            if (i < 10){
                printf ("%i %i %#04x %#04x %#04x    image1\n",i,j,r1,g1,b1);
                printf ("%i %i %#04x %#04x %#04x    image2\n",i,j,r2,g2,b2);
    }

void get_pixel_rgb(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y, uint8_t *r, uint8_t *g, uint8_t *b) 
{
Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *)surface->pixels; 
SDL_GetRGB (pixels[(y*surface->w)+x], surface->format, r, g, b);
}
```

So with the same bitmap image I would expect the pixel values of r1 to be identical to r2, and g1 to g2 etc. But instead, they are coming out wildly different. Here are some of the outputs:

```
x y   r    g    b
9 468 0000 0x8e 0x0c    image 1
9 468 0xa5 0x09 0000    image 2

9 469 0000 0000 0000    image 1
9 469 0000 0xa5 0x09    image 2

9 470 0000 0x8e 0x0c    image 1
9 470 0x53 0xff 0xbc    image 2

9 471 0000 0000 0000    image 1
9 471 0xa6 0x09 0000    image 2
```

Anyone have an explanation on why they are different? Or another way I can get this data without having to display the images on screen?

Comment: Unrelated, but you do know that in the declaration `uint8_t r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2 = 0xFF;` only `b2` will be initialized?

Comment: Also unrelated but worth verifying that those `SDL_LoadBMP` calls succeeded and that you're not just reading some random memory. Also that the image actually is 480 pixels high and that you're not reading out of bounds.